# Oracle 11g get all matched occurrences by a regular expression

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm using Oracle 11g and I would like to use the REGEXP_SUBSTR to match all the occurrences for a given pattern.
For example

```
 SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148',
  '(^|\s)[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5,}(\s|$)') "REGEXP_SUBSTR"
  FROM DUAL;
```

returns only the first match Ta233141  but I would like to return the other occurrences that match the regex, meaning Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

REGEXP_SUBSTR only returns one value. You could turn your string into a pseudo-table and then query that for matches. There's an XML-based way of doing this that escapes me at the moment, but using connect-by works, as long as you only have one source string:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
FROM (
    SELECT 'Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148' AS str FROM DUAL
)
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^ ]+')) + 1;
```

... gives you:

```
SUBSTR             
--------------------
Txa233141b           
Ta233141             
Ta233142             
Ta233147            
Ta233148
```

... and you can filter that with a slightly simpler version of your original pattern:

```
SELECT substr
FROM (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]+', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148' AS str
        FROM DUAL
    )
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^ ]+')) + 1
)
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(substr, '^[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5,}$');

SUBSTR             
--------------------
Ta233141             
Ta233142             
Ta233147             
Ta233148
```

Which isn't very pretty, but neither is holding multiple values in one field.

Comment: this code doesnot return Ta233148. To get that change  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^ ]+')) to  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^ ]+'))+1

Comment: Using this code directly with anything but a simple splitter character will return way to many results.
Replace LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '[^ ]+'))+1 with REGEXP_COUNT(str, '[^ ]+') and you will get the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little late, but I needed basically the same thing and could not find a good snippet. I needed to search a free text column of a table for some terms and collect them.  As this might be useful to another I have included a version based on this question. While REGEXP_SUBSTR only returns one value, Oracle also provides a REGEXP_COUNT to tell you how many matching items are present in a given string, therefore you can join this with a list of indexes to select each as follows (with examples from this query as free text from some 'source_table'):

```
DEFINE MATCH_EXP = "'(^|\s)[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{5,}'"

WITH source_table
     -- Represents some DB table with a 'free_text' column to be checked.
     AS (       ( SELECT 'Txa233141 Ta233141 Ta232 Ta233142 Ta233141 Ta233148'
                             AS free_text FROM dual )
          UNION ( SELECT 'Other stuff PH33399 mixed in OS4456908843 this line'
                             AS free_text FROM dual )
        )
   , source
     -- For some table, select rows of free text and add the number of matches
     -- in the line.
     AS ( SELECT cnt
               , free_text
          FROM ( SELECT RegExp_Count(free_text, &MATCH_EXP) AS cnt
                      , free_text 
                 FROM source_table )
          WHERE cnt > 0 )
   , iota
     -- Index generator
     AS ( SELECT RowNum AS idx
          FROM dual
          CONNECT BY RowNum <= ( SELECT Max(cnt) FROM source ) )
-- Extract the unique 'cnt' matches from each line of 'free_text'.
SELECT UNIQUE
       RegExp_SubStr(s.free_text, &MATCH_EXP, 1, i.idx) AS result
FROM   source s
  JOIN iota i
    ON ( i.idx <= s.cnt )
ORDER BY result ASC
;
```

It has the advantages of working for any list of selected rows and uses the CONNECT BY minimally (as this can be very slow).

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a function that will loop through and return all of the values?

```
create or replace function regexp_substr_mr (
  p_data clob,
  p_re varchar
  )
return varchar as
  v_cnt number;
  v_results varchar(4000);
begin
  v_cnt := regexp_count(p_data, p_re, 1,'m');
  if v_cnt < 25 then
    for i in 1..v_cnt loop
      v_results := v_results || regexp_substr(p_data,p_re,1,i,'m') || chr(13) || chr(10);
    end loop;
  else 
    v_results := 'WARNING more than 25 matches found';
  end if;

  return v_results;
end;
```

Then just call the function as part of the select query.

Comment: In principle I prefer this approach as in my opinion it has more general application than the accepted solution. I would however improve it by passing in p_data, p_re, and flags and creating a type something like "create or replace type mytype is table of varchar2(4000)" and return that from the function. One could then embed it in SQL something like as follows: select A.id,X.column_value from someTable A cross join table(regexp_substr_mr(A.textToSearch,'regexp') X

Answer (score 1):

I am fix @Alex Poole [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17597049/6784078) for multi-line source support and for more quickly executing:

```sql
with templates as (select '\w+' regexp from dual)
select 
    regexp_substr(str, templates.regexp, 1, level) substr
from (
    select 1 id, 'Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148' as str from dual
    union
    select 2 id, '2 22222222222222Ta233141 2Ta233142 2Ta233147' as str from dual
    union
    select 3 id, '3Txa233141b 3Ta233141 3Ta233142' as str from dual
)
join templates on 1 = 1
connect by 
    id = connect_by_root id
    and regexp_instr(str, templates.regexp, 1, level) > 0
order by id, level
```

Source lines:

```
ID  STR                                             
--  ----------------------------------------------  
1   Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148  
2   2 22222222222222Ta233141 2Ta233142 2Ta233147    
3   3Txa233141b 3Ta233141 3Ta233142
```

Result:

```
Txa233141b              
Ta233141                
Ta233142                
Ta233147                
Ta233148                
2                       
22222222222222Ta233141  
2Ta233142               
2Ta233147               
3Txa233141b             
3Ta233141               
3Ta233142
```

Comment: Your query return error: "ORA-30007: CONNECT BY ROOT operator is not supported in the START WITH or in the CONNECT BY condition". How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Base on @David E. Veliev [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596363/oracle-11g-get-all-matched-occurrences-by-a-regular-expression/41068794#41068794), this is query for multi rows input. If below query work for you, consider vote up [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596363/oracle-11g-get-all-matched-occurrences-by-a-regular-expression/41068794#41068794).

```
SELECT SUBSTR
  FROM (WITH TEMPLATES AS (SELECT '\w+' REGEXP FROM DUAL)
         SELECT ID,
                CONNECT_BY_ROOT ID CBR,
                LEVEL LVL,
                REGEXP_SUBSTR(STR, TEMPLATES.REGEXP, 1, LEVEL) SUBSTR
           FROM (SELECT 1 ID,
                        'Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148' AS STR
                   FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                 SELECT 2 ID,
                        '2 22222222222222Ta233141 2Ta233142 2Ta233147' AS STR
                   FROM DUAL
                 UNION
                 SELECT 3 ID,
                        '3Txa233141b 3Ta233141 3Ta233142' AS STR
                   FROM DUAL)
           JOIN TEMPLATES
             ON 1 = 1
         CONNECT BY REGEXP_INSTR(STR, TEMPLATES.REGEXP, 1, LEVEL) > 0)
          WHERE ID = CBR
          GROUP BY ID,
                   CBR,
                   LVL,
                   SUBSTR
          ORDER BY ID,
                   LVL;
```

Input:

```
ID  STR
==  ==============================================
1   Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148
2   2 22222222222222Ta233141 2Ta233142 2Ta233147
3   3Txa233141b 3Ta233141 3Ta233142
```

Output:

```
SUBSTR
======================
Txa233141b
Ta233141
Ta233142
Ta233147
Ta233148
2
22222222222222Ta233141
2Ta233142
2Ta233147
3Txa233141b
3Ta233141
3Ta233142
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
  LISTAGG(REGEXP_SUBSTR('Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148', '(^|\s)[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5,}',1,level) 
         ) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 1)
  AS REGEXP_SUBSTR
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY level<=regexp_count('Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148','(^|\s)[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5,}')
;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The below is the easy solution for your question.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Txa233141b Ta233141 Ta233142 Ta233147 Ta233148',
  '([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s?){1,}') "REGEXP_SUBSTR"
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: That just returns the original string; it includes Txa233141b even though that starts with three non-numeric characters, not two as the OP's pattern requires.