# Why does this regexp match a single line: ([^' || chr ( 10 ) || ']*)(' || chr ( 10 ) || '|$) in Oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle

I just don't understand, why this matches a whole line:

```
'([^' || chr ( 10 ) || ']*)(' || chr ( 10 ) || '|$)'
```

What I understand so far is:

```
(' || chr ( 10 ) || '|$)
```

matches the end of a line `$` OR a linebreak `chr ( 10 )`

But why does THIS

```
([^' || chr ( 10 ) || ']*)
```

match ANYTHING before my first linebreak?

```
    with Text as
       (select    'This is my first line'
               || chr ( 10 )
               || 'This is my second line'
               || chr ( 10 )
               || 'This is my third line'
                 as Astr
          from dual)
select regexp_substr ( Astr
                      ,'([^' || chr ( 10 ) || ']*)(' || chr ( 10 ) || '|$)' ) First_Line
  from Text
```

I just don't get it.

Comment: It looks clear: your expression is `[^\n]*` which means *0 or more characters other than a newline symbol*. `chr(10)` is `\n`. Just go to [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) and see for yourself.

Comment: The regex basically boils down to `([^\n]*)(\n|$)`. The code is rather hard to read. Not sure if there is any way to specify new line character in Oracle literal string, or in the regex syntax supported by Oracle.

Comment: Right. Here is [how it works](https://regex101.com/r/yM1mF2/1). And a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a066c/1). Default number of occurrences in Oracle [`regexp_substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) is `1` *meaning that Oracle searches for the first occurrence of `pattern`*. To get multiple matches, refer to [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17597049/3832970).

Comment: Ok, I misinterpreted the caret "^" as the "beginning of the line" and not as a whole "[^\n]" as "Anything, but a linebreak".
Thank you!