# REGEXP_REPLACE to replace emails in a list except a specific domain

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, regexp-replace

I am novice to regular expressions. I am trying to remove emails from a list which do not belong to a specific domain.

for e.g. I have a below list of emails:

```
John@yahoo.co.in , Jacob@gmail.com, Bob@rediff.com,
Lisa@abc.com, sam@gmail.com , rita@yahoo.com
```

I need to get only the gmail ids:

```
Jacob@gmail.com, sam@gmail.com
```

Please note we may have spaces before the comma delimiters.
Appreciate any help!

Comment: use  like%gmail.com        as Select * from Table_name where Email like %gmail.com

Comment: Fix your data model.  Don't store lists in strings.  That is not the SQLish way of storing lists.

Comment: Use REPLACE_REGEXP function where you will define the expressions matching the domains to be filtered out and replacing them with empty strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than suppress the emails not matching a particular domain (in your example, `gmail.com`), you might try getting only those emails that match the domain:

```
WITH a1 AS (
    SELECT 'John@yahoo.co.in , Jacob@gmail.com, Bob@rediff.com,Lisa@abc.com, sam@gmail.com , rita@yahoo.com' AS email_list FROM dual
)
SELECT LISTAGG(TRIM(email), ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY priority )
  FROM (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(email_list, '[^,]+@gmail.com', 1, LEVEL, 'i') AS email
         , LEVEL AS priority
      FROM a1
   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(email_list, '[^,]+@gmail.com', 1, 'i')
);
```

That said, Oracle is probably not the best tool for this (do you have these email addresses stored as a list in a table somewhere? If so then @GordonLinoff's comment is apt - fix your data model if you can).

Answer (score 2):

This could be a start for you.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                                  '[[:alnum:]\.\+]+@gmail.com',
                                  1,
                                  LEVEL)
                      AS SUBSTR
              FROM (SELECT ' John@yahoo.co.in , Jacob.foo@gmail.com,   Bob@rediff.com,Lisa@abc.com, sam@gmail.com , sam.bar+stackoverflow@gmail.com, rita@yahoo.com, foobar '
                              AS str
                      FROM DUAL)
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH (REGEXP_REPLACE (str, '[^,]+')) + 1)
 WHERE SUBSTR IS NOT NULL ;
```

Put in a few more examples, but an email checker should comply to the respective RFCs, look at wikipedia for further knowledge about them https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/17597049/869069

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using a CTE just for a different take on the problem.  First step is to make a CTE "table" that contains the parsed list elements.  Then select from that.  The CTE regex handles NULL list elements.

```
with main_tbl(email) as (
  select ' John@yahoo.co.in , Jacob.foo@gmail.com,   Bob@rediff.com,Lisa@abc.com, sam@gmail.com , sam.bar+stackoverflow@gmail.com, rita@yahoo.com, foobar '
  from dual
),
email_list(email_addr) as (
  select trim(regexp_substr(email, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1))
  from main_tbl
  connect by level <= regexp_count(email, ',')+1
)
-- select * from email_list;
select LISTAGG(TRIM(email_addr), ', ') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY email_addr )  
from email_list
where lower(email_addr) like '%gmail.com';
```