# keep string based on substring

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I need to keep on the line those words that includes part of a sub-string. Ex:

```
select regexp_substr('libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64, python-kitchen-1.1.1-5.el7.noarch, nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64, git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64', 
       '(.+?)(devel|git|nfs).+?\,') st from dual;
```

This query returns **libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64**, but I also need **git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64** and **nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64** based on the pattern. Note that I have dozens of words on each row (not only those 4) so I need to adjust the pattern, to expand the result (like adding grub, perl, etc).
Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596363/oracle-11g-get-all-matched-occurrences-by-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your regex; it will match (for example) `python-kitchen-1.1.1-5.el7.noarch, nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64,` because it allows space and commas before the match to one of `devel`,`git` or `nfs` (in `(.+?)`). Also, it won't match `git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64` because it requires a comma at the end of the match. You can fix those issues by replacing `(.+?)` with `[^ ]*` and `\,` with `(,|$)`. Then you can use a solution derived from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596363/oracle-11g-get-all-matched-occurrences-by-a-regular-expression) (although in my preferred form, checking for `NOT NULL` in the `CONNECT BY`) to get all your results:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]*(devel|git|nfs).+?(,|$)', 1, level) AS lib
FROM (
  SELECT 'libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64, python-kitchen-1.1.1-5.el7.noarch, nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64, git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64' as str
  FROM dual
)
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]*(devel|git|nfs).+?(,|$)', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
LIB
libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64,
nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64,
git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64
```

Note this leaves commas on the end of some of the names, if you want to get rid of them, just use `RTRIM`:

```
SELECT RTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]*(devel|git|nfs).+?(,|$)', 1, level), ',') AS lib
FROM (
  SELECT 'libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64, python-kitchen-1.1.1-5.el7.noarch, nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64, git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64' as str
  FROM dual
)
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]*(devel|git|nfs).+?(,|$)', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
```

Output:

```
LIB
libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64
nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64
git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64
```

If you want to get all the values on one line, you can use the first query as a `CTE` and then use `LISTAGG` on the result:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT level AS l, REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]*(devel|git|nfs).+?(,|$)', 1, level) AS lib
  FROM (
    SELECT 'libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64, python-kitchen-1.1.1-5.el7.noarch, nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64, git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64' as str
    FROM dual
  )
  CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[^ ]*(devel|git|nfs).+?(,|$)', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT LISTAGG(lib) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY l) AS lib
FROM CTE
```

Output:

```
LIB
libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64,nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64,git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=676ecebc433644adf697c5cfa5f06b76)

Comment: I clicked your answer as useful, but as I mentioned, I need to keep the result on the same row, not separated. I actually tried to use (without success):                                                 select regexp_replace('libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64, python-kitchen-1.1.1-5.el7.noarch, nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64, git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64', 
       '[^ ]*(devel|git|nfs).+?(,|$)', '\1, ') st from dual;     Using TRIM is the easy part, I need this result: libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-39.0.3.el7.x86_64, git-1.8.3.1-20.el7.x86_64, nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.65.0.1.el7.x86_64.Thanks

Comment: @misurex Apologies - I missed that part of the question. The easiest way to get the result on one line is to `LISTAGG` the result of the first query as trying to replace things which do not match is quite tricky, especially without lookaheads. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I can use this workaround, thank you.