# regexp_substr all occurence of doc. XXX

Tags: oracle, plsql, regexp-substr

Here a sample code:

```
set define off;
drop table brol;

create table brol
(
br varchar2(4000)
);

INSERT INTO brol ( br ) VALUES ( 'Proposition de décret institutionnalisant l assemblée citoyenne et le conseil citoyen, déposée par Madame Schyns (Doc. 221 (2019-2020) N° 1 et 1bis)
Proposition de décret spécial modifiant les articles 2, 5, 6 et 7 du décret spécial du 19 juillet 2018 instituant la consultation populaire, déposée par Madame Schyns (Doc. 222 (2019-2020) N° 1)
Proposition de modification du Règlement du Parlement de Wallonie visant à institutionnaliser les assemblées citoyennes et conseils citoyens, déposée par Madame Schyns (Doc. 223 (2019-2020) N° 1)
Rapporteur : Monsieur Sahli
Proposition de décret spécial modifiant les articles 2, 5, 6 et 7 du décret spécial du 19 juillet 2018 instituant la consultation populaire en vue d octroyer un droit d initiative aux commissions délibératives composées de députés et de citoyens tirés au sort, déposée par Madame Schyns, Messieurs Desquesnes, Antoine et Bastin (Doc. 278 (2020-2021) N° 1)
Désignation d un Rapporteur 
Discussion - Votes
' );

commit;

select * from brol;
```

When i execute the next query:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)') from brol;
```

i have as result:

```
Doc. 221
```

That a first good step and I was very happy to find it...
But I need also to have as return:

```
Doc. 222 
Doc. 223
Doc. 278
```

I m not able to have all 3 at the same moment..
Could you please help me to find what i forgot in the regexp_substr ?

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)',1,1) from brol;
```

Doc. 221

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)',1,2) from brol;
```

Doc. 222

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)',1,3) from brol;
```

Doc. 223

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)',1,4) from brol;
```

Doc. 278

Is there a way to know how many I ll find ?
==> nO it s not possible..

I found the approach with a function https://stackoverflow.com/a/23683522/10710461

```
create or replace function regexp_substr_mr (
```

p_data clob,
p_re varchar
)
return varchar as
v_cnt number;
v_results varchar(4000);
begin
v_cnt := regexp_count(p_data, p_re, 1,'m');
if v_cnt < 25 then
for i in 1..v_cnt loop
v_results := v_results || regexp_substr(p_data,p_re,1,i,'m') || chr(13) || chr(10);
end loop;
else
v_results := 'WARNING more than 25 matches found';
end if;

return v_results;
end;

But i m not able to adapt it...

Thx,

R.D

Comment: The function was working perfectly but not my call...
select regexp_substr_mr(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)' ) from brol;
It s working !

Answer (score 1):

You have the right query and just use `connect by` to find all,

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)',1,level) 
  from brol
connect by REGEXP_SUBSTR(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)',1,level) is not null;
```

Comment: This will work if there is only a single row in the table; if there are multiple rows then this will generate exponentially increasing numbers of duplicate rows as the `CONNECT BY` clause is not correlated to the previous row.

Comment: @MT0, you are right and this was never part of the OP's original question. You are one step ahead which is fine but I am well aware of the fact it is not for all rows and it can be surely done for all if the requirement asks.

Comment: And if OP is on 12c or greater it can be done very easily using `cross apply` or `lateral`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to know how many I'll find?

Use `REGEXP_COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_COUNT( br, 'Doc\.\s+\d+' ) AS num_docs
FROM   brol;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | NUM_DOCS |
> | -------: |
> |        4 |
> ```

Your function appears to output a CR-NL separated list of docs. Instead you can use:

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(
         REGEXP_REPLACE( br, '.*?(Doc\.\s+\d+\.?|$)', '\1' || CHR(13) || CHR(10), 1, 0, 'n' ),
         CHR(13) || CHR(10)
       ) AS docs
FROM   brol
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | DOCS     |
> | :------- |
> | Doc. 221 |
> | Doc. 222 |
> | Doc. 223 |
> | Doc. 278 |
> | :------- |
> ```

If you want the values on separate rows (and can have multiple rows in your `brol` table) then you can use:

```sql
WITH docs ( br, doc, lvl, num_docs ) AS (
  SELECT br,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( br, 'Doc\.\s+\d+\.?', 1, 1 ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( br, 'Doc\.\s+\d+\.?' )
  FROM   brol
UNION ALL
  SELECT br,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( br, 'Doc\.\s+\d+\.?', 1, lvl + 1 ),
         lvl + 1,
         num_docs
  FROM   docs
  WHERE  lvl < num_docs
)
SELECT doc
FROM   docs
WHERE  lvl <= num_docs;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | DOC      |
> | :------- |
> | Doc. 221 |
> | :------- |
> | Doc. 222 |
> | :------- |
> | Doc. 223 |
> | :------- |
> | Doc. 278 |
> | :------- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8d5040547fdb3744ec9c4c66614c973c)*

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I added yet another column to your table - `ID` (which kind of *uniquely* identifies each row).

```
SQL> desc brol
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 BR                                                 VARCHAR2(4000)
```

I also added another row into the table by modifying `INSERT` you posted; it contains two "Doc." values.

Finally, such a query might return what you want:

```
SQL> select id,
  2    regexp_substr(br, 'Doc\.\s+\d+.?', 1, column_value) result
  3  from brol cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  4                                           connect by level <= regexp_count(br, 'Doc\.')
  5                                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  6  order by id, result;

        ID RESULT
---------- ----------
         1 Doc. 221
         1 Doc. 222
         1 Doc. 223
         1 Doc. 278
         2 Doc. 666
         2 Doc. 777

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

the function was perfect.. My call was not...

```
select regexp_substr_mr(br,'Doc. ([[:alnum:]]+\.?)' ) from brol;
```

It s working.
Thank you all for your answer. I ll check what is exactly the "connect" option cause I dont know it. I m in a package so it s easy for me to add a function.