# Split string by space and '-' SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have the following column value:

```
test-00 - test-01 - test-02
```

I need to get the string between ' -' and ' -'

```
test-01
```

Is it possible in SQL Server?

I've tried with :

```
STRING_SPLIT(column, ' -')
```

but it works only for `'-'` not for `' -'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and data population, start
DECLARE @tbl Table  (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Tokens) VALUES
('test-00 - test-01 - test-02'),
('test-03 - test-04 - test-05');
-- DDL and data population, end

SELECT ID, Tokens
    , PARSENAME(c, 2) as [token-in-between]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (REPLACE(Tokens, ' - ','.'))) AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
| ID |           Tokens            | token-in-between |
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
|  1 | test-00 - test-01 - test-02 | test-01          |
|  2 | test-03 - test-04 - test-05 | test-04          |
+----+-----------------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `replace()` to make a single character delimiter:

```
string_split(replace(column, ' - ', '|'), '|')
```

I am guessing you understand the rest of the logic because you mention splitting the string this way in your question.

Comment: I have an additional question, is it possible to select only the second part od that string?

Comment: @inspiredd . . . Yes, but that did not appear to be your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the  following:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT 'test-00 - test-01 - test-02' AS x
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'test-03 - test-04 - test-05'
),
cteRn AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) rn
  FROM cte
),
cteSplit AS(
SELECT rn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY value) rnFilter, TRIM(value) AS value
  FROM cteRn
  OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(x, ' -', '|'), '- ', '|'), '|')
)
SELECT value
  FROM cteSplit
  WHERE rnFilter = 2
```

However, this will only work as long as you really want to split by '- ' and ' -'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '[ - ]+', 1, NULL) AS substr
FROM (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS str FROM DUAL
)
```

Refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/17597049/2429434

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method

```
 --==== Some test data
Declare @testData Table (TestData varchar(100));
Insert Into @testData (TestData)
Values ('test-00 - test-01 - test-02')
     , ('test-03 - test-04 - test-05');

 Select col1 = substring(v.TestData, 1, p1.pos - 2)
      , col2 = substring(v.TestData, p1.pos, p2.pos - p1.pos - 1)
      , col3 = substring(v.TestData, p2.pos, p3.pos - p2.pos - 1)
   From @testData                                                               As td
  Cross Apply (Values (concat(replace(td.TestData, ' - ', '|'), '|||')))        As v(TestData)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('|', v.TestData, 1) + 1))                      As p1(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('|', v.TestData, p1.pos) + 1))                 As p2(pos)
  Cross Apply (Values (charindex('|', v.TestData, p2.pos) + 1))                 As p3(pos)
```